# How to use trim and avoid NPE by using collections.sort?

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-8, comparator

There is a Class `Role`, having data member as String `roleName`. I have to sort a list of `Role`.
While sorting I need to check NPE and trim `roleName` also. So I used

```
roleList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Role::getRoleName, 
    Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

I can suppress the null pointer exception but can't use `trim`.

```
roleList.sort( (x, y) -> x.getRole().trim().compareTo(y.getRole().trim()));
```

Using this I can't avoid NPE.

Comment: You are getting NPE because: x.getRole() could be null value and you are calling null.trim() resulting into NPE.. Same thing is happening with y.getRole().trim().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
roleList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Role::getRoleName,
    Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(String::trim))));
```

Comment: Indeed. I was slower :) On the other aspect, a `Function` to extract role name looks a bit cleaner when it has to deal with custom logic.

Comment: @Naman, I think your answer provide better re-usability by creating an Function to handle null trimming.

Comment: @samabcde It might have been, but it was pointing in the same direction and that is why I have left a comment here as well.

Comment: @Naman it becomes even cleaner and simpler when not addressing two concerns in one function. After all, there is this `nullsLast` comparator already guarding another comparator. Just use `Comparator.comparing(Role::getRoleName, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing( String::trim)))`